# Laravel - The [login] attribute is required Sentry2 Auth

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, cartalyst-sentry

Any idea's why i get the following error

The [login] attribute is required - what does it mean?

when trying to login with Sentry 2 & Laravel.?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use anything different from `login` as attribute in your users table, email for example, first publish the Sentry config:

```
php artisan config:publish cartalyst/sentry
```

Then open file `app\config\packages\cartalyst\sentry\config.php` and edit:

```
'login_attribute' => 'email',
```

Comment: Perfect. I had no idea Sentry2 could publish the configuration